# How to randomize pictures for a Slots App in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swiftui, shuffle

I am making a pretty simple slots app in SwiftUI (for the purposes of learning the language) and I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the "Spin" button it changes the pictures but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I am thinking something like putting the pictures in a list, and then shuffling them using the .shuffle() method and then finally using a for loop to pick out each picture and display it on screen but I am just not able to accomplish that for any reason.

---

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var credits = 50
    @State private var Slot1 = "apple"
    @State private var Slot2 = "cherry"
    @State private var Slot3 = "star"
    @State var pictures = ["apple", "cherry", "star"]

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Slots using SwiftUI")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(.top, 50.0)
                Spacer()
                Text("Credits: "+String(credits))
                    .font(.title2)
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    // Randomize the 3 pictures
                    
                    
                    
                    // "Print" the three pictures
                    Image(Slot1).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Image(Slot2).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Image(Slot3).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: { }, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        Text("Spin")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        
                        let shuffled = pictures.shuffled()
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                })
                
                Spacer()
            
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Layout/Design**
[image: Final Design And Layout Wanted]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in action of Button, like this in code, use `random` in **range** of `pictures.indices`:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var credits = 50
    @State private var Slot1 = "apple"
    @State private var Slot2 = "cherry"
    @State private var Slot3 = "star"
    @State var pictures = ["apple", "cherry", "star"]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Slots using SwiftUI")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(.top, 50.0)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Credits: " + credits.description)
                    .font(.title2)
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Image(Slot1).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Image(Slot2).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Image(Slot3).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    Slot1 = pictures[Int.random(in: pictures.indices)]    //<<: Here!
                    Slot2 = pictures[Int.random(in: pictures.indices)]    //<<: Here!
                    Slot3 = pictures[Int.random(in: pictures.indices)]    //<<: Here!
                    
                }, label: {
                    
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        
                        Text("Spin")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response just a quick question... What does the `pictures.indicies` method do exactly?

Comment: You are welcome, it return Range of pictures array for using inside random function.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like:

```
func shuffle() {
   Slot1 = pictures[Int.random(in: 0..<3)]
   Slot2 = pictures[Int.random(in: 0..<3)]
   Slot3 = pictures[Int.random(in: 0..<3)]
}
```

and call it on Button action.